# Restart AUTO_INCREMENT field in delphi

Tags: delphi, field, restart

I'm using firebird database and trying to restart id column as *AUTO_INCREMENT*

field after DELETE
like the following code:

```
  SQLQuery1.Close;
  SQLQuery1.SQL.Text :='DELETE FROM MY_TABLE';
  SQLQuery1.ExecSQL;
  //---------------------------------------------------------
  SQLQuery1.Close;
  SQLQuery1.SQL.Text :=
    'ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE ALTER COLUMN ID AUTO_INCREMENT =1';
  SQLQuery1.ExecSQL;
```

But I cannot do that. Only DELETE SQL command works.
And how TRUNCATE works?
The following code not works in delphi too:

```
  SQLQuery1.Close;
  SQLQuery1.SQL.Text :=
    'TRUNCATE TABLE MY_TABLE';
  SQLQuery1.ExecSQL;
```

Thank you

Comment: Use the [Firebird Documentation](https://www.firebirdsql.org/en/documentation/) to find out what your particular Firebird version does or does not support. And spell it `INCREMENT` instead of `ENCREMENT`.

Answer (score 2):

After Delete all records try the below codes,

```
  SQLQuery1.Close;
  SQLQuery1.SQL.Text := 'SET GENERATOR ID TO 1';
  SQLQuery1.ExecSQL;
```

Note that 1 will be the current value for the generator! You might want to set it to 0.

If does not work try this method published in firebirdnews

REF : https://www.firebirdnews.org/rfc-truncate-table-in-firebird/

```
TRUNCATE TABLE <target table> [ <identity column restart option> ]

<identity column restart option> ::=
CONTINUE IDENTITY
| RESTART IDENTITY
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried your answer but it return this bug **invalid request BLR at offset 5 generator ID is not defined.**

Comment: Probably the generator for column ID in MyTable is not named ID but something else. You can try this something else in the SET GENERATOR command instead.